# Auto update database in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to have a auto refresh or update on my database every time i insert data, but it keeps on duplicating my database and you need to manually click the refresh button to see the updated table.

Here are my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Public Class Form2

    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim Command As MySqlCommand
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogout.Click
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Insert into databse.employeeinfo (idEmployeeInfo,name,surname,age) values ('" & tbEID.Text & "', '" & tbUname.Text & "', '" & tbPassword.Text & "', '" & tbAge.Text & "')"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("Data Save")

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
        Load_Form()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Update databse.employeeinfo set idEmployeeInfo = '" & tbEID.Text & "', name = '" & tbUname.Text & "', surname = '" & tbPassword.Text & "', age = '" & tbAge.Text & "' where idEmployeeInfo = '" & tbEID.Text & "' "
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated")

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Delete from databse.employeeinfo where idEmployeeInfo = '" & tbEID.Text & "' "
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted")

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Load_Form()
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader

            While READER.Read
                Dim sName = READER.GetString("name")
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(sName)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(sName)
            End While

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo where name= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader

            While READER.Read
                tbEID.Text = READER.GetInt32("idEmployeeInfo")
                tbUname.Text = READER.GetString("name")
                tbPassword.Text = READER.GetString("surname")
                tbAge.Text = READER.GetInt32("age")
            End While

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo where name= '" & ListBox1.Text & "'"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader

            While READER.Read
                tbEID.Text = READER.GetInt32("idEmployeeInfo")
                tbUname.Text = READER.GetString("name")
                tbPassword.Text = READER.GetString("surname")
                tbAge.Text = READER.GetInt32("age")
            End While

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Load_Form()
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter

        Dim bSource As New BindingSource


        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)


            SDA.SelectCommand = Command
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
            SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLOADdb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLOADdb.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse"
        Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
        Dim bSource As New BindingSource


        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo"
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)


            SDA.SelectCommand = Command
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
            bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
            SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim Row As DataGridViewRow
            Row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

            tbEID.Text = Row.Cells("idEmployeeInfo").Value.ToString
            tbUname.Text = Row.Cells("name").Value.ToString
            tbPassword.Text = Row.Cells("surname").Value.ToString
            tbAge.Text = Row.Cells("age").Value.ToString

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbSearch.TextChanged
        Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("name Like '%{0}%'", tbSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After each call to update or delete a record in your database you need to execute code that will update the results in your form.

So at the end of `btnDelete_Click` and `btnUpdate_Click` you need to call `Load_Form()` the same way you are doing in `Button1_Click_1`

Besides that here's a few tips for you.

**NEVER** send raw data to a SQL query or you are opening you application up to attacks. For example. If someone where to enter `Pwnd'; Drop Table employeeinfo; --` into `tbUname.Text` your employee info table would be deleted.

Instead, **Always** send user input as parameters in a parameterized query.

Data Adapters are useful but are quite slow. It is faster to build your own Data Table.

Take advantage of the ability to reuse code and create a class for your data access so you don't need to write code to take care of opening connections, initializing commands and handling errors every time you want data:

```
Public Class MySqlHelper
    Public Shared Function GetConnection() As MySqlConnection
        Return New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=Password;database=databse")
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ExecuteReader(Query As String) As MySqlDataReader
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = GetConnection()
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
            dr = Command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Return dr
        Catch ex As Exception
            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()
            conn = Nothing
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ExecuteReader(Query As String, ByVal Params() As String, ByVal Values() As Object) As MySqlDataReader
        If Params Is Nothing OrElse Values Is Nothing OrElse Params.Length = 0 OrElse Params.Length <> Values.Length Then
            Throw New ArgumentException()
        End If
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = GetConnection()
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim Command As New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
            For I As Integer = 0 To Params.Length - 1
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(Params(I), Values(I))
            Next
            dr = Command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Return dr
        Catch ex As Exception
            conn.Close()
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ExecuteScalar(Query As String) As Object
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = ExecuteReader(Query)
        Dim result As Object = Nothing
        If dr.Read Then
            result = dr(0)
        End If
        dr.Close()
        Return result
    End Function
    Public Shared Function ExecuteScalar(Query As String, ByVal Params() As String, ByVal Values() As Object) As Object
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = ExecuteReader(Query, Params, Values)
        Dim result As Object = Nothing
        If dr.Read Then
            result = dr(0)
        End If
        dr.Close()
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetDataTable(Query As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Try

            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = ExecuteReader(Query)
            If dr.Read Then

                For i As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
                    dt.Columns.Add(dr.GetName(i))
                Next
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow
                For i As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
                    row(i) = dr(i)
                Next
                dt.Rows.Add(row)
                While dr.Read
                    row = dt.NewRow
                    For i As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
                        row(i) = dr(i)
                    Next
                    dt.Rows.Add(row)
                End While
            End If
            dr.Close()
            Return dt

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Throw
        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

As you can see the Class has overloads that allow you to send arrays of Parameter Names and Values. These will then be added to your command using 'Command.AddWithValue` so that your commands aren't susceptible to Sql Injection attacks.

You can reuse that class any time you need database access and even in other projects. Using the class you code can be rewritten like this:

```
Public Class Form2
    Inherits Form
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogout.Click
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Query As String = "Insert into databse.employeeinfo (idEmployeeInfo,name,surname,age) values (@EID,@Uname,@Pwd,@Age)"
        Try
            MySqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(Query, {"@Eid", "@Uname", "@Pwd", "@Age"}, {tbEID.Text, tbUname.Text, tbPassword.Text, tbAge.Text})
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Load_Form()


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Dim Query As String = "Update databse.employeeinfo setname=@uname,surname=@surname,age=@age where idEmployeeInfo=@eid"
        Try
            MySqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(Query, {"@Eid", "@Uname", "@Pwd", "@Age"}, {tbEID.Text, tbUname.Text, tbPassword.Text, tbAge.Text})
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        Load_Form()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Dim Query As String = "Delete from databse.employeeinfo where idEmployeeInfo=@eid"
        Try
            MySqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(Query, {"@Eid"}, {tbEID.Text})
            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted")
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)


        End Try
        Load_Form()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            Dim Query = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo"
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Query)
            While dr.Read
                Dim sName = dr.GetString("name")
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(sName)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(sName)
            End While
            dr.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Load_Form()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try

            Dim Query As String = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo where name=@Name"
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Query, {"@name"}, {ComboBox1.Text})
            If dr.Read Then ' no need for while since we are only reading single record
                tbEID.Text = dr.GetInt32("idEmployeeInfo")
                tbUname.Text = dr.GetString("name")
                tbPassword.Text = dr.GetString("surname")
                tbAge.Text = dr.GetInt32("age")
            End If
            dr.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            Dim Query As String = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo where name=@Name"

            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Query, {"@name"}, {ListBox1.Text})

            If dr.Read Then ' no need for while since we are only reading single record
                tbEID.Text = dr.GetInt32("idEmployeeInfo")
                tbUname.Text = dr.GetString("name")
                tbPassword.Text = dr.GetString("surname")
                tbAge.Text = dr.GetInt32("age")
            End If


        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public DbDataSet As DataTable
    Private Sub Load_Form()

        Dim bSource As New BindingSource
        Try
            Dim Query As String = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo"
            DbDataSet = MySqlHelper.GetDataTable(Query)
            bSource.DataSource = DbDataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLOADdb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLOADdb.Click

        Dim bSource As New BindingSource
        Try
            Dim Query As String = "Select * from databse.employeeInfo"
            DbDataSet = MySqlHelper.GetDataTable(Query)
            bSource.DataSource = DbDataSet
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim Row As DataGridViewRow
            Row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

            tbEID.Text = Row.Cells("idEmployeeInfo").Value.ToString
            tbUname.Text = Row.Cells("name").Value.ToString
            tbPassword.Text = Row.Cells("surname").Value.ToString
            tbAge.Text = Row.Cells("age").Value.ToString

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tbSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbSearch.TextChanged
        Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("name Like '%{0}%'", tbSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `MySqlHelper` should be a `Module`, because don't have any "instance" logic.

Comment: That's actually how I use it for myself.